# Primitive cohomology of cubic fourfolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I cant find the definition of the primitive cohomology and the intuition of it. Could someone help ? especially when working on cubic fourfolds maybe we have an easier definition ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Some context would help.  Where did you encounter primitive cohomology?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the ambiguity. For example page 16 of the paper : special cubic fourfolds september 1998 of Brendan Hasset. He considers H^2(S,C)_0 of a K3 surface